# Infinispan cluster and hotrod client wont communicate

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

I have a replication cluster whit a couple of nodes - they can communicate freely between each other. I also have a Hotrod Server joining the cluster (I can see that its recognized by the other nodes). But when I connect a Hotrod Client to the server, and try to put something into the cache, I get an exception on:

- the hotrod client:
  `org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request
  for message id[4] returned server error (status=0x85):
  org.infinispan.CacheException: Problems invoking command.`
- the hotrod server: `Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Type of
  data read is unknown. Id=-2147482548 is not amongst known reader
  indexes.`
- a node with a cachestore: `WARN: Problems unmarshalling remote
  command from byte buffer org.infinispan.CacheException: Type of data
  read is unknown. Id=-2147482548 is not amongst known reader indexes.`

Also the Hotrod client doesn't see any of the changes provided by other nodes. If there aren't any nodes in the cluster besides the hotrod server - everything works. If any other node (for example with a CacheListener registered) is available, I get the mentioned exceptions.

I use Infinispan 5.1.5.Final and JGroups 3.0.10.Final everywhere. Win7 64 Bit, Java 6_0_32 32bit. All nodes are working on one machine, and the cluster is built on TCP transport stack. Every node is a Java SE application. There was a similar post on the infinispan forum (https://community.jboss.org/thread/199539) but its for an older version (the update helped in this case).

Someone had a similar issue, or has any idea where I should look for the source of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind... Solved by myself

I've added a dependency to the cluster nodes pom (those which are NOT the hotrod servers):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
  <artifactId>infinispan-server-hotrod</artifactId>
</dependency>
```